# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python

I have tried to attached a file to the mail using python. 
Code:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTPException


def send_Email():
    file1="abc.txt"
    message = "Test mail"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg.attach(MIMEText(file(file1).read()))

    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp server name',port)
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, EmailId, message, msg.as_string() )
        print "Successfully sent email"
    except SMTPException:
        print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Bt I have get the error: socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

full error message:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 249, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Looks like socket lib can't resolve SMTP server name.

Comment: Does this SMTP server even have an A record

Comment: might be a VPN issue. if you want to handle err code use this code.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160652/7640131

Answer (score 12):

I know for sure that gaierror comes up when you are working from behind proxy.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the DNS lookup for 'smtp server name' is failing - if this is your exact code then you can see why - if not and you have the valid qualified name for the SMTP server then you may have issues with the firewall/internet connection, etc., also port has to be set to a valid value to match your servers SMTP configuration, (usually port 25 **but** not absolutely always).

Answer (score 2):

The below answer may be quite irrelevant to the question. But,some users may have a different scenario.

If a server can be reached only through VPN and if we try to reach it with VPN disconnected, this error : "gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed" crops up.

Connect to VPN and then executing the code should work good.

Comment: yes Correct, VPN is one of the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I tried using flask-mail
I just had to resend the message and it worked perfectly well.
I don't know why I got the  error the first time perhaps it might be a bug in the library...

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a *host* problem. Using debug mode, I spotted that in (host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM) I got *host=local* and it should be *host=localhost*.
In the run.py I defined *localhost* and the file hosts (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) was defined *local*. 
They have to be equal, otherwise you get the socket.gaieeror.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in urllib3 version 1.25.9 package. This produced "socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed" error for me (working from behind an authenticated proxy server).
Downgrading to urllib3 version 1.25.8 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you might did a little mistake in settings.py file..
check your code one more time in your settings file
settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your_email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to login using your credential. Try:

```
 smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp server name',port)

 smtpObj .starttls() 
 smtpObj .login(email, password)
 smtpObj.sendmail(sender, EmailId, message, msg.as_string() )
 print "Successfully sent email"
```

Answer (score -2):

I prefer u guys to run the file as administrator for eg
open cmd as administrator then 
type 
**cd C:\into ur .py file path**
and then type
**python filename.py**

it worked for me. 
good luck

Answer (score -2):

You need to activate IMAP/SMTP service active for your host mail.