I can't open my .py file without using idle, I would like to run it using cmd
When I open my file, cmd opens very quickly and closes,the "data" is other file, If you know something I should improve, please let me know :D(its my first app, this is just the beginning)
main.py:
import smtplib
from data import *
import time

#verificar o provedor do email para startar servidor#
while True:
    email_type = str(input("What's your e-mail provider?")).lower()

    if email_type == "gmail":
        host = gmail["host"]
        port = gmail["port"]
        break
    elif email_type == "outlook":
        host = outlook["host"]
        port = outlook["port"]
        break
    else:
        print("We don't have support with this e-mail provider")
        time.sleep(1)
        pass

server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()

while True:
    login = str(input(white_text + "Login: "))
    password = str(input("password: "))

    try:
        server.login(login, password)
        print(green_text + "Login successfully")
        break
    except:
        print(red_text + "Login and/or password")
        pass


When I open my file, cmd opens very quickly and closes How, exactly, are you opening the file?

Open cmd.exe window, cd to the directory of main.py, and run it: py main.py, OR add input('press a key to continue') as the last line of your script to keep it open and run it as you are now.

When invoking python from the command line use python -i <filename.py> (or python.exe -i <yourFileName.py>) to "inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal".  In other words, this will leave you in a python prompt when your program has run, and you can inspect variables and call function from your script.

If I am correct, you are opening the Python file from 'File Explorer' (using double click). We have to execute the file from the Command prompt(CMD).
Can you share: how you execute this script from the command prompt?
Code review:
Note: You used the While loop, it is unnecessary and you used `input()'. Try with hardcoded value for the practice later you can add input().
You can refer to my answer for SMTP:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545321/python-smtp-error-code-handling/76160652#76160652
