# [python3]socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, sockets

I know that there are many similar answers to the question, use VPN and unblock it from firewall,
but tried all and nothing seems to work. So, I added the question as a last resort.

I am new to python, I tried what they say and didn't understand the theory behind the answers that I found.
spec:
windows 10.
python 3.8.

edit :
I am getting the error while binding(s.bind()).

here is the code:

```
import socket

class server():
hostname = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = input("Enter port(8080 is default): ")

if port == '':
    port = 8080
else:
    port = int(port)
print(socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port))

if socket.has_ipv6:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
else:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((hostname, port))
s.listen()


while True:

    (clientConnected, clientAddress) = s.accept()

    a = input("{0} is Trying to connect on port {1}\n Do want to Accept request:(Yes/y/No/n): ".format(hostname, port))

    if a == 'Yes' or a == 'y':
        print("You are connected to " + hostname)
        clientConnected.send("Succesful".encode())
        break
        # break

    if a == 'No' or a == 'n':
        print("Quitting.......")
        s.close()

    else:
        print("Invalid request .. \n Try again")
        continue


if __name__ == "__main__" :
sever().run()
```

output:

```
C:\Users\Haseeb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe "D:/Product Code_ 037396/Python/Tv_Remote/Server_1.py"
Enter port(8080 is default): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Product Code_ 037396/Python/Tv_Remote/Server_1.py", line 3, in <module>
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('127.0.0.1', 8080))]
class server():
File "D:/Product Code_ 037396/Python/Tv_Remote/Server_1.py", line 18, in server
s.bind((hostname, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How should I resolve this?
thanks you.

Comment: have you had a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400208/socket-gaierror-errno-11001-getaddrinfo-failed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [socket.gaierror: \[Errno 11001\] getaddrinfo failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400208/socket-gaierror-errno-11001-getaddrinfo-failed)

Comment: This Answers aren't helping it ,as I mentioned it abow, its a simple socket server. I am not doing any smtp service or doing any proxy stuff. I want to know why I am getting this error and how to fix it.